# Why "Comment with Block comment" is always disabled in PyCharm 1.5.4?

Tags: pycharm

I have found that the menu Code | "Comment with Block comment" is always disabled.

How to fix it?

Comment: There is an open feature request about it in Pycharm issue-tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6185, please vote for it to increase its priority and be notified about updates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because in Python, there is no such thing as a block comment.

The `""" stuff here """` is for documentation.

Comment: And obviously you will do that for commenting one line, sure. Instead of putting a hash in front of it with a command.

Comment: And I found that the """ comment """ could only be used once, at the top in a .py file in PyCharm. The next time I surrounded some lines, they were interpreted as string.

Answer (score 6):

Ctrl+/ (un)comments all selected lines. Agree it is not intuitive, but works

Answer (score 4):

While it's true that Python doesn't have block comments, I've recently switched from Aptana Studio and that had a nice block comment format which preserved spaces/idents, allowed you to uncomment by block and supported wrapping which was neat.

```
###############################
# a = b
# code_block = commented_out
###############################
```

I guess you can't have everything!

Answer (score 4):

The Code | "Comment with Block Comment" stays grayed out if pycharm does not know the syntax for adding comments for the particular file type. You can configure this in File | Settings, then select Editor/File Type. Select the Recognized File type that you want to configure comments for, or add it if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs (Wingware, PyCharm) allow you to select a range of lines and then type the `#` character (Wingware), select <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> (PyCharm), or other method.  This comments out each line by placing `#` just before the first none-white character in each line.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, In PyCharm for commenting out the code, we use Hash symbol `#`, shortcut keys are:

- For a single line comment we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> , for uncomment do it again.
- For multiline comments we select those lines and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> , for uncommenting do it again while keeping those lines selected.

Comment: Thank you. It works for mac with ```cmd+/```.